# How to determine where max_user_connections occur

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Unfortunately I encountered with a '`max_user_connections`' problem in MySQL. I'm using shared hosting so '`max_user_connections`' value is set to 8 and as I experimented a little bit on my localhost using WAMP I found out that I need that value to be at least 32.

What are possible ways to determine at what place in script '`max_user_connections`' exceeds number 8, so I can try to optimize database queries or such. I'm using PHP PDO and I read somewhere that connections are closed automatically, anyway should I try it to close it manually, maybe it doesn't close at the right time.

All suggestions of what I should try are welcome.

Comment: are you closing the connection after using it?? or left it open??

Comment: I tried to create __destruct method and unset it but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

After using the connection, its safe to close them.

```
<?php
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $dbh = null;// setting to null will close your connection
?>
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) for more info(see example 3)

Comment: Unfortunately, If I close the connection too early it says: Call to a member function query() on a non-object. Because value becomes null.

Comment: U closed the connection before executing the query??

Comment: My fault, but thanks :), this example actually works but it didn't solve the problem, I managed to solve my problem using PDO singleton implementation.